# Change motion using script in Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

Hi how do we change motion in an AnimatorController using script in Unity Editor?

The red highlight is the one I'd like to change, but using script
[image]

[image]

- My use case is to copy animations from one object, process the animation e.g. adding offset rotation, then add to another object. Since my object has many child objects, I need to create a script to automate this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the `AnimatorController` via editor scripts is always quite tricky!

- First of all you need to have your `AnimationClip` from somewhere

  ```c#
  // somewhere get the AnimationClip from
  var clip = new AnimationClip();
  ```
- Then you will have to cast the [`runtimeAnimatorController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-runtimeAnimatorController.html) to an [`AnimatorController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorController.html) which is only available in the Editor! (put `using UnityEditor;` at the top of the script!)

  ```c#
  var controller = (AnimatorController)animator.runtimeAnimatorController;
  ```
- Now you can get all its information. In your case you can probably use the default layer (`layers[0]`) and its [`stateMachine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorStateMachine.html) and according to your image retrieve the `defaultState`:

  ```c#
  var state = controller.layers[0].stateMachine.defaultState;
  ```

  or find it using [Linq `FirstOrdefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) (put `using System.Linq;` at the top of the script) like e.g.

  ```c#
  var state = controller.layers[0].stateMachine.states.FirstOrDefault(s => s.state.name.Equals("SwimmingAnim")).state;

  if (state == null)
  {
      Debug.LogError("Couldn't get the state!");
      return;
  }
  ```
- Finally assign the `AnimationClip` to this state using [`SetStateEffectiveMotion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorController.SetStateEffectiveMotion.html)

  ```c#
  controller.SetStateEffectiveMotion(state, clip);
  ```

---

Note however that even though you can **write** individual animation curves for an animation clip using [`SetCurve`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.SetCurve.html) unfortunately it is not possible to **read** them properly so it will be very difficult to do what you want

> copy animations from one object, process the animation e.g. adding offset rotation, then add to another object.

You will have to go through [`AnimationUtility.GetCurveBindings`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationUtility.GetCurveBindings.html) which gets quite complex ;)

Good Luck!

Comment: yes, this's exactly wat I'm looking for! Thanks @derHugo. I have to agree this is really pain in the *ss. I have also been through `AnimationUtility` to create `AnimationClip` from scratch and changing the keyframes one by one.